# How to open a page using the title in php?

Tags: php

I am working on a real estate website. I want to display details of each property on `xyz.com/propert-details.php`.

Right now I am displaying data using the id of each property example link `xyz.com/property-details?id=3`.

However, I want to use slug generated from property title in url. I have converted title of property to slug.

I want an url like `xyz.com/property-tile`.

What is the right direction? I will do implementation myself.

Comment: Right direction if you're using an Apache sever is htaccess file, mod_rewrite

Comment: It would be also nice if you would end your sentences with a ".". Freddy has right that mod_rewrite is the best solution, but if you can't do it, the $_SERVER["INFO_PATH"] could be also usable.

Answer (score 2):

To prettify the url you need to edit .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?id=$1 [QSA,NC]
```

As far as I got, you want to get property-title using the id in the url. 
You need to do something like this:

```
if (isset($_GET['id']))
{
// check for the id in the database and return the name 
// redirect user using header("Location:xyz.com/".urlencode($row['name']));
}
```

Comment: See, how I beautified your answer. :-) [This](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291362/advice-for-non-native-english-speakers/291370#291370) checklist could help you a lot.